# Android, issue with finding saved file on storage

Tags: android, android-intent

I am downloading a file(PDF) from server using `DownloadManager` and request is

```
request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(this,Environment.getDataDirectory().getPath(), filename);
```

The File gets save in my internal storage under

```
"MyFiles->All files/DeviceStorage/Android/data/myPackage/files/data/"
```

For opening the saved file i use the following code

```
File sdCardRoot = new File(Environment.getDataDirectory().getPath());
if(sdCardRoot.exists()){
    for (File f : sdCardRoot.listFiles()) {
        if (f.isFile())
            name1 = f.getName();

            String path = f.getPath();

            Log.e("UriFile", ""+Uri.parse(path));
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(path), "application/pdf");
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
```

But it shows document cannot be opened, But i can see the file in the location and can open it directly not from my app.

I have a SD card inserted and there is a similar folder structure created in sdcard as well .

I guess while opening the file it searches the folder on `SDCARD` not my `internal storage`, how to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added permissions in AndroidManifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: I have added the  permissions.

Comment: Is it searching in the sdcard or the internal storage. Could you please make it sure

Comment: the file is saved in "Internal Storage" but intent is searching in the "Sdcard".

Comment: Try this:  File sdCardRoot = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString());

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Actually the issue was i have to use "intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(listOfFiles), "application/pdf");" i was using uri.parse(listOfFiles)

Answer (score 0):

As your file is stored in app internal storage i.e **/data/data/packagename/** use **getFilesDir()** to get the path of directory holding application files & use **listFiles()** to get all files inside returned path directory.

> **getFilesDir()** - Returns the absolute path to the directory on the filesystem where files created with openFileOutput(String, int) are stored. No permissions are required to read or write to the returned path, since this path is internal storage.

OR you can use **getExternalFilesDir(String type)** to get the path of directory where you app files are saved & iterate through files using **listFiles()**.

> **getExternalFilesDir(String type)** - Returns the absolute path to the directory on the primary external filesystem (that is somewhere on Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()) where the application can place persistent files it owns. These files are internal to the applications, and not typically visible to the user as media.

Usage Example:

```
public void listFilesInAppInternalStorage(){

    //using getFilesDir()
    File filesDir = getFilesDir();
    File filesList[] = filesDir.listFiles();
    for(File file: filesList){
         Log.i(TAG, "FileName:" + file.getName());
    }

    //using getExternalFilesDir()
    File extFilesDir = getExternalFilesDir(null);   
    File listOfFiles[] = extFilesDir.listFiles();
    for (int i=0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++)
    {
        Log.v(TAG, "FileName:" + listOfFiles[i].getName());
        Log.d(TAG, "FilePath:" + listOfFiles[i].getAbsolutePath());
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Actually the issue was i have to use "intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(listOfFiles), "application/pdf");" i was using uri.parse(listOfFiles).

Comment: Welcome!! you can post your own answer and accept it, if this issue has been resolved.